# Who's right here? g++ or Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, reference, visual-studio-2017, g++, undefined-behavior

Recently I came across a funny "feature". 
The code below compiles equally on both g++ and Visual Studio 2017.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int *> l;
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    l.emplace_back(&a);
    auto p = l.front();
    std::cout << p << '\n'; // prints x
    l.erase(l.begin());
    l.emplace_back(&b);
    std::cout << p << '\n'; // prints x
    std::cin.get();
}
```

However, if you change line

```
auto p = l.front();
```

to

```
auto & p = l.front();
```

Visual Studio still gives the same output (considering the address x may change, of course). However, now g++ gives me the output

```
x
x+4
```

Obviously, when passing the pointer by reference, g++ recognizes that the first element of the list now has a different value, which is a different address of the stack (offset + 4 compared to the initial one), while Visual Studio 2017 doesn't. So... who's broken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> who's broken?

Both are correct, because your code has undefined behavior.

After `auto & p = l.front();`, you [erased](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) the element from the `list`, then `p` becomes dangled; any dereference on it leads to UB, means anything is possible.

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

Answer (score 4):

After `l.erase(l.begin());` reference to first item previously obtained at `auto & p = l.front();` becomes invalid and accessing value stored in p leads to Undefined Behavior. So it is your code that is broken.